# excel 2010 parse out sections of a variable length text string

Tags: excel, string, parsing, split

I have data that normally comes in as CMB1.I2.CB3.str01/02+ or 01-02.01+ or some random variation on that set up. I believe the worst case one is AR1.IN2.CM3.ST04/05+.

Right now I have the full string data in col A2-A1000, in col B, C ,D etc I am trying to separate the full string by parts.  I'm separating the string by using `left , mid, len and search` functions in excel, and by having users input the separator ( in this case all ., but sometimes -, or / , etc). so my formulas look like this

Using this example `AR1.IN2.CM3.ST04/05+` is in cell A5 and separators / deliminator (.'s) are in the cells `B2 - D2`

A5 : `AR1.IN2.CM3.ST04/05+`
A6 : `A1.I2.CM3.ST06/07-`
A7 : `01.03.4.8/9+`

B5 : AR1
eq in b5 : `=LEFT(A5,SEARCH($B$2,A5,1)-1)`

C5 : IN2
eq in C5 : `=MID(A5,LEN(B5&$B$2)+1,SEARCH($C$2,A5,LEN(B5&$B$2)+1)-LEN(B5&$B$2&$C$2))`

D5 : CM3
eq in D5 : `=MID(A5,LEN(B5&$B$2&C5&$C$2)+1,SEARCH($D$2,A5,LEN(B5&$B$2&C5&$C$2&$D$2)+1)-LEN(B5&$B$2&$C$2&C5&$D$2))`

E5 : ST04/05+
eq in E5:  `=RIGHT(A5,LEN(A5)-LEN(B5&$B$2&C5&$C$2&D5&$D$2))`

My equations work fine but I was hoping there was a simpler way? My coworkers eyes glaze over when I try to explain to them what each formula is doing

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shorten your formulas, you could:

1. Add helper columns storing the locations of the first, second, etc., appearances of your separators. This will save you lots of reading/writing, but most of all, it will make your formulas much more readable/understandable.
   This is an essential concept in programming, and I think formulas in Excel should abide by this rule as well.
2. Add helper columns with partial results of stripping parts of your strings. These might be hidden, grouped, and/or very narrow so they do not bother. `SUBSTITUTE` and `FIND` may be useful here.
3. Use the VBA function [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) (partially leaves the *Formulas* realm). I like this one very much, and I use it often in User Defined Formulas.
4. Use Text to Columns (completely leaves the *Formulas* realm).

Your coworkers looks would go back to normal...

Comment: I have the separators above the columns where the data is split. Those are the locked cells in the formula. I have a ton of VBA code that runs around this step, i left it as a formula so that if my coworkers needed to adjust it they could with the formulas. I will look into the split vba function. I already have helper columns way off to the side of the sheet

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach.  With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,".",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

Copy this both across and downwards.  For example:

[image]

This is like"Text-to-Columns", but with a formula.

Comment: this is a cleaner formula for sure. I'm assuming that if I change the `"."` to a cell reference nothing should break. The separators are often just `.`, but they can be literally any character. I'll mess around with this and post results once I have a solution

Comment: Very nice method!

Comment: The only issue with this method is that for some reason when the separator is a `-` sign, the equation omits the - from the end of the string. i might not have mentioned it before but the `+` and `-` on the end are polarities and need to be tracked. otherwise awesome formula.